# AngularJS : interactions between graphics

Tags: angularjs

I realized a GUI. My web page consists of 8 graphics. There is a barchart for dates, a map for the country, a datatable for companies, etc.
Now I wish to establish the interactions between graphics. For example, if the user clicks the date 2010, so you have the map and the table displays the results of the 2010 data.
(I think I have to make a $ scope in a controller that will contain all the data, but after how to recover the data for each chart, and then to say "if click on 2010 when ..."?)

Can you please tell me how to do, what steps?

Thank you !

Comment: You haven't asked about a concrete problem here, you have asked for evaluation of project requirements.  Any attempt at answering your question would be writing a solution from scratch, which, aside from being way too broad, is also virtually impossible without in depth knowledge of your project data.

Comment: Ok. And do you know how to retrieve the value of the object on which I click. For example if I have a barchart, what used to take the value of 2010 if the user clicks on that date?

Comment: without seeing your code, it's just a guess, but probably `ng-model` or `ng-click`.

Comment: you should [edit] your question rather than posting your code as an answer to the question.  That being said, the code you posted in the answer is JQuery, not Angular.

Comment: So, I can't recover the value (when the user clic) with angularjs ?

Comment: not without a lot of extra work, unless you switch to using an angular module like angular-highcharts (https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)